# How to use SQLMap/Burp to perform SQL injection on a form that is behind another form

Tags: sql-injection, burp-suite, sqlmap

I have a form that takes in an IP address and loads that page (Acts as a Web Application Proxy). The page that gets loaded has an SQL injection vulnerability. How can I use SQLMap or BURP to exploit this?

Note: I cant use the --proxy option since this is not a normal proxy because I have to enter the IP and click "Browse" to load a page. So I have to first issue a post request, and then another post request, the second post request has an SQL injection vulnerability.